# return 5th element from last in linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Above question was asked to me in my interview.
Though I am still waiting for the result, I am wondering  if my approach is correct or if there is any better solution?

```
 struct Node  
 {   
  int data;  
  Node * next;    
 };  
 Node *function( struct Node *head)   
 {    
    if ( ! head)   
    {   
        std::cout <<" no linked present";  
        return 0;  
    }  

    Node  *current, *temp;  
    temp = NULL;
    current = head;  
    int counter = 0;  
    while( current != NULL)   
    {
        counter ++;  
        current = current->next;   
        if( counter >= 5)   
        {
            if( temp == NULL)  
                temp = head;   
            else
            temp = temp->next;  
        }  

    }  
     return (temp);    
   }
```

IF you guys have better optimal solution , please post it here.
Thanks to everyone
Sam

Comment: by the way, where is `temp` declared?

Comment: @Vlad, Thanks for pointing it out. I have made the changes

Comment: okay, with the new edit: you forgot to initialize `temp` with `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping me out and many thanks to Vlad and Nick  for pointing out my silly mistake which cost be dearly during interview process

Comment: I don't think a sane interviewer would base his/her decision on whether you declared all the temporaries. In the real life, the first attempt to compile the code would report the uninitialized variable to you immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the single-linked list your solution should be optimal. For the double-linked list, you could go from the back.

Comment: Please check out the edit in my answer, you made a good point but I explained it further.

Answer (score 1):

If you exclude the case where the list is less than 5 elements long, I would say the next solution is a bit more elegant, but it's essentially the same thing:

```
Node *function( struct Node *head)  
{
   while ( head->next->next->next->next )
      head = head->next;
   return head 
}
```

Performance-wise, for a single-linked list, you can't do better than `O(n)`, so all that can be improved is the readability.

EDIT:

Vlad made an interesting point in the comments, that in every iteration of the loop more instructions are performed. I believe that is wrong, as pointer access only requires 1 asm instructions. However, in the OP's code:

```
   counter ++;  
   current = current->next;   
   if( counter >= 5)   
   {
       if( temp == NULL)  
           temp = head;   
       else
           temp = temp->next;  
   }
```

are the instructions executed in the loop. This is way less efficient. Increment, 2 pointer assignements and 2 comparisons...

Both are `O(n)`, but for large inputs it matters whether the time is 4*n or 10*n.

Comment: Your solution is more elegant, but does more in each iteration. The OP's solution makes only two advances (and one increment, which could be eliminated). As well, the OP's solution can be parametrized, whereas yours has 5 hardcoded.

Comment: @Vlad I will update my answer, please read, you might find it interesting.

Comment: well, in order to be more efficient I would make small changes in the OP's code: (1) increase the `counter` only if `counter < 5` (in the `else` clause) (2) skip check `if (temp == NULL)` and initialize `temp` by `head` before the loop (this would require a one-time check whether counter is < 5 or not before `return`). This way we have: 2 indirect accesses, 2 assignments and 1 comparison per iteration. In your case, we've got 5 indirect accesses and 2 assignments per iteration.

Comment: "pointer access only requires 1 asm instructions", sure but pointer indirection requires memory access which, since we're generalizing, is way worse. Also all the accesses will depend on each other unlike the OPs code. </pedantic>

Comment: @Vlad I'm pretty sure the compiler can optimize better than the two of us. A lot better. I don't have a compiler on hand as I'm not using my computer right now, but I'm pretty sure that with full optimization(no point comparing performance without optimization) the generated code would be similar. If you can do it, please post the generated code for both cases.

Comment: We could optimize the OP's code even more by splitting in 2 loops, first 5 iterations + the rest, thus getting rid of comparison.

Comment: @Vlad , "if (temp == NULL) and initialize temp by head before the loop (this would require a one-time check whether counter is < 5 or not before return). " But to my understanding this will return temp = head  even when list is less than 5 ??

Comment: @samprat: in order to prevent that, we need to check the counter before return (`one-time check whether counter is < 5`), and see whether we need to return `temp` or `NULL`.

Comment: @Vlad there's no point in arguing without concrete facts :). We both have valid points, only optimized machine code can settle this. Even if my version requires a couple of extra instructions (which I doubt it does), I would still use it since it is a lot more readable.

Comment: @Luchian: I don't have a compiler right now as well, sorry :(

Comment: @Vlad And honestly, if you were debugging this code, which one would you rather see?

Comment: @Luchian: I'm ok to debug any :-) Unless it's in Visual Basic.

Comment: Even if we accept that the optimizer will make all possible correct implementations equivalent, so that all that matters is code style, I think I prefer `Node *current = head->next->next->next->next->next; while ((current = current->next)) head = head->next; return head;`. I may be out-by-one. For me, it's just as clear what's going on, it takes stuff out of the loop that doesn't need to be there, and it's obvious how to parameterize the 5 and/or check for too-short lists without touching the loop. Also, I suspect in fact it is easier for the optimizer, but I can't be bothered to check either.

Answer (score -1):

That looks like it would work fine. Only issue is that you have not declared temp in your code, and have not initialized it to NULL.